# select result except strings in_array with sql

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have code like this:

```
$p = $db->query("SELECT ads_id FROM ads_submissions WHERE status = '0'");
$c_ads = array();
while($row = $db->fetchAll($p))
{
    $c_ads[] = $row;
}
```

Output

```
4 6 9
```

I want to add this line to $new_ads = $db-> after WHERE

```
AND ads_id = !in_array('$output', $c_ads)
```

To select all ads_id except id 4 and 6 and 9

```
$new_ads = $db->fetchOne("SELECT ads_id FROM ads_pack WHERE allowed_countries LIKE '%".$country_tr."%'");
```

But this never work correctly.

Any help please ?

Thank you.

Comment: what is your goal? why select all ads with status '0' and afterwards select all not in this result? Wouldn't it be easier to change the where clause??

Comment: @sailingthoms, the OP is referencing different tables in the two queries.  Although a JOIN might work here.

Comment: using a join would definitely a better way and much more performant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do it like this

```
AND ads_id NOT IN ( implode(',', $c_ads) )
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as `in array` in sql. There's simply result sets. you want

```
AND ads_id NOT IN (4,6,9)
```

Comment: So i just need to use AND ads_id NOT IN ($c_ads) without any changes ?

Comment: well, you'd still have to implode the array. you can't embed a PHP array in sql directly. e.g. `$sql = "... WHERE field NOT IN (" . implode(',', $array) . ")"`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you rewrite this using a subquery, instead of running 2 queries?

```
"SELECT ads_id FROM ads_pack WHERE allowed_countries LIKE '%".$country_tr."%' AND ads_id NOT IN (SELECT ads_id FROM ads_submissions WHERE status = '0')"
```